# Why won't my AngularJS Controller take control on state change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm in the very beginning stages of learning AngularJS. I have a couple of years of Webdev experience (JS, HTML, etc.) so JS is not new to me.

I'm going through the tutorial at https://thinkster.io/tutorials/mean-stack. I'm still on the front-end part. I haven't even reached the Node/Express/Mongodb topics yet! It's pretty great but the ability to see the full work-in-progress requires paying for a membership which I don't feel is necessary at this point. If I had that I might be able to see what's different about my code but, alas.

As I usually do, I've changed a few semantic details from the tutorial (e.g. "persons" instead of "posts") but they shouldn't alter the functionality of the page fundamentally.

The trouble is, I can't get my controller to "take control" as it were, in its various states. The tutorial uses ui-router. I'm under the impression there are other alternatives for routing (e.g. "ngrouter?") and that is all well and good but I would like to get this work just on principle.

Here is the code:

app.js

```
var moduleApp = angular.module('flapperNews', ["ui.router"]);

moduleApp.config([
    "$stateProvider",
    "$urlRouterProvider",
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)
    {
        $stateProvider
            .state("home",
            {
                "url": "/home",
                "templateUrl": "/home.html",
                "controller": "MainCtrl"
            });

        $stateProvider
            .state("friends",
            {
                "url": "/friends/{id}",
                "templateUrl": "/friends.html",
                "controller": "FriendsCtrl"
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("home");
    }
]);

moduleApp.factory("persons", [
    function(){
        return {
            "persons": [
                {
                    "name":    "John",
                    "age":     31,
                    "friends": [
                        {"name": "Brynn", "relationship": "Wife"},
                        {"name": "Becca", "relationship": "Sister"}
                    ],
                    "homePage": "http://www.google.com"
                },
                {
                    "name":    "Brynn",
                    "age":     30,
                    "friends": [
                        {"name": "John", "relationship": "Husband"},
                        {"name": "Becca", "relationship": "Sister-in-Law"}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name":    "Becca",
                    "age":     26,
                    "friends": [
                        {"name": "John", "relationship": "Brother"},
                        {"name": "Becca", "relationship": "Sister-in-Law"}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        };
    }
]);
```

controllers.js

```
moduleApp.controller("MainCtrl", [
    "$scope",
    "persons",
    function($scope, persons) {
        the_scope = $scope;
        $scope.test = 'Hello world!';
        $scope.persons = persons.persons;
        $scope.addPerson = function() {
            if (typeof $scope.name !== "undefined" && $scope.name !== "" &&
                typeof $scope.age !== "undefined" && $scope.age !== "" &&
                !isNaN($scope.age))
            {
                $scope.persons.push({"name": $scope.name, "age": $scope.age, "homePage": $scope.homePage});
                $scope.name = "";
                $scope.age = "";
                $scope.homePage = "";
            }
        };
        $scope.getOlder = function(post) {
            post.age++;
        };
        $scope.getYounger = function(post) {
            post.age--;
        };
    }
]);

moduleApp.controller("FriendsCtrl", [
    "$scope",
    "$stateParams",
    "persons",
    function($scope, $stateParams, persons)
    {
        $scope.friends = persons.persons[$stateParams.id];
    }
]);
```

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Angular App!</title>

        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <script src="controllers.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="flapperNews"><!-- ng-controller="MainCtrl"-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <ui-view></ui-view>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">
                <form ng-submit="addPerson();">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input id="name" type="text" ng-model="name">

                    <br />

                    <label for="age">Age</label>
                    <input id="age" type="text" ng-model="age">

                    <br />

                    <label for="homePage">Home Page</label>
                    <input id="homePage" type="text" ng-model="homePage">

                    <br />

                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add Person</button>
                </form>
                <div>
                    {{ test }}
                </div>
                <div ng-repeat="person in persons | orderBy: '-age'">
                    <span ng-click="getYounger(person);">-</span>
                    <span ng-click="getOlder(person);">+</span>
                    <a ng-show="person.homePage" href="{{person.homePage}}">{{ person.name }}</a>
                    <span ng-hide="person.homePage">{{ person.name }}</span>
                     -
                    Age: {{ person.age }}
                    <span>
                        <a href="#/friends/{{ $index }}">Friends</a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1>Flapper News</h1>
            </div>
        </script>

        <script type="text/ng-template" id="/friends.html">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h3>
                    <a ng-show="person.homePage" href="{{person.homePage}}">{{ person.name }}</a>
                    <span ng-hide="person.homePage">{{ person.name }}</span>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div ng-repeat="friend in person.friends | orderBy: '-age'">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" ng-click="getOlder"></span>
                {{ friend.name }} - {{ friend.relationship }}
            </div>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a functional [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qeyoyemaya/edit?html,js,console,output) to peruse. When you click one of the "Friends" button it initiates a state change. Note the jsbin combines the two js files.

Even with the initial state ("/home") the controller is not working though. The tutorial specifically says you shouldn't need the "ng-controller" directive in "body" tag so that shouldn't be the problem. Incidentally, when I **do** have the "ng-controller" directive in the "body" tag the controller does appear to work which suggests the controller definition is sound.

I'm sure I'm missing some small crucial semantic error but I've been working on this for days (in what little time I've had outside of taking care of our infant) and can't figure it out. I'd really like to move on in the tutorial but I feel like I'm probably missing something important.

To pre-empt the community members who are fond of drinking the haterade:

- I don't know anything.
- I'm a terrible programmer.
- I'm barely qualified to use a toaster.
- Please ignore this post's pathetic usage of SO server storage.

Now that that's been said... anyone who is still reading and actually feels like throwing an Angular noob a bone please help.

Thanks!

Comment: The reason your controllers don't work is because they are out of their scope. They can only affect stuffs that are inside ui-view. If I were you I would put the second <div class="row"> inside home.html.

Comment: @NghiaTran. That's it!!!!!! Thank you very much. The tutorial didn't explain that very clearly (or maybe I missed it). I'm back on track. If you want to make your comment an official answer I'll accept it. Either way, thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: A -1 without an explanation? I guess I did not dispell the haters afterall.

Comment: I will negate the -1. This is to me, quite a well-elaborated question

Comment: Well, thank you for that @CozyAzure. I just appreciate learning something from a down vote so I can improve the content of my questions in the future.

Comment: Been there, done that. Everyone starts from somewhere. Sometimes I do heavily condemn the self-righteous "pros" in the community. It's not healthy at all